# Explain Connect by level in SQL different behaviour in these two queries

Tags: sql, oracle

**1.**

```
select level,t.*
from 
( select 'name' from dual
  union all
  select 'name' from dual
) t
connect by level<=3;
```

Gives result:

```
LEVEL NAME
----- ----
    1 name
    2 name
    3 name
    3 name
    2 name
    3 name
    3 name
    1 name
    2 name
    3 name
    3 name
    2 name
    3 name
    3 name
```

**2.**

```
SELECT level, 'name' name
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

while this gives -

```
LEVEL NAME
----- ----
    1 name
    2 name
    3 name
```

Please Help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not the best explainer, but this should help you understand what's happening (the query below is equivalent to yours, I just added operators [connect_by_root](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) and [sys_connect_by_path](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)). Each rectangle from image is a row in output.

[image]

Your second, simpler query gets only leftmost branch as there is no second "root name" to connect.

```
with t as (
  select 'name1' name from dual 
  union all 
  select 'name2' name from dual)
select rownum, level, name, 
    sys_connect_by_path(name, '/') path, 
    connect_by_root(name) root
  from t 
  connect by level<=3;

    ROWNUM      LEVEL NAME  PATH                  ROOT
---------- ---------- ----- --------------------- -----
         1          1 name1 /name1                name1
         2          2 name1 /name1/name1          name1
         3          3 name1 /name1/name1/name1    name1
         4          3 name2 /name1/name1/name2    name1
         5          2 name2 /name1/name2          name1
         6          3 name1 /name1/name2/name1    name1
         7          3 name2 /name1/name2/name2    name1
         8          1 name2 /name2                name2
         9          2 name1 /name2/name1          name2
        10          3 name1 /name2/name1/name1    name2
        11          3 name2 /name2/name1/name2    name2
        12          2 name2 /name2/name2          name2
        13          3 name1 /name2/name2/name1    name2
        14          3 name2 /name2/name2/name2    name2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in a couple of additional conditions to enable Oracle to determine the correct rows to loop round:

```
with t as (select 'name1' col1 from dual union all
           select 'name2' col1 from dual)
select t.col1, level lvl
from   t
connect by level <= 3
           and prior t.col1 = t.col1
           and prior dbms_random.value is not null;

COL1         LVL
----- ----------
name1          1
name1          2
name1          3
name2          1
name2          2
name2          3
```

You can see an explanation of why you need the `and prior dbms_random.value is not null` (N.B. some people prefer to use `sys_guid()` instead of `dbms_random.value`) condition [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535).